# Random Timeout on EF commands

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two program and use database to send message between them.
so i should check database actively for change. with less than 100 records, randomly my program fail to query database and throw `Timeout Exception`!

It is a win Form application which use Entity Framework 6 with .Net 4.6.1 and c#. I use background worker to check Database and do the stuff.

```
private void Bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
       try
       {
           var req = context.Requests.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == RequestStatus.NotProccesed);
           if (req != null)
           {
               req.Status = RequestStatus.InProccess;
               context.SaveChanges();
               Task.Factory.StartNew((requestObj) =>
               {
                   //Do the Stuff...
               }, req);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    } while (!bg.CancellationPending);
}
```

randomly i get SQLServer Timeout in "FirstOrDefault" or "SaveChanges" Functios.

Comment: Did you profile the SQL query EF produces? How long does it take to run if you run directly against the database?

Comment: I didn't, but it shouldn't get more than 1 second a small query on a small table with less than 100 records!.

Comment: Using a `context` from outside the scope of the background worker event handler spells trouble. Create a new context in the event handler.

Comment: Right! Solve the problem!